# Procmail content as POST variable

Tags: shell, procmail

Procmail should send my emails with the content to my api. No matter what I try, I get the subject etc., but I can't get to the content. The $CONTENT variable is filled with the subject.

```
:0
{
 :0 w
  | CONTENT= cat

 :0
 | URL=$(curl -d  "content=$CONTENT" -d "title=Logged Activity" https://myapi.de/fetch.php);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a repeated syntax error;

```
:0 w
| CONTENT= cat
```

means assign an empty string to `CONTENT` for the duration of the `cat` command. I guess your intent is to assign the message's contents to the variable. The syntax for that would be

```
CONTENT=| cat
```

(not a recipe, so no `:0 w` is useful, necessary, or correct here); but if you don't use this variable for anything else, there really is no need to assign it separately.

```
:0
| URL=$(curl -d  "content=$(cat)" -d "title=Logged Activity" https://myapi.de/fetch.php);
```

As above, this also probably doesn't do what you actually want. If you expect the variable to be assigned within your `.procmailrc`, try

```
URL=|curl -d "content=$(cat)" -d "title=Logged Activity" https://myapi.de/fetch.php;
```

The trailing semicolon (or some other character from `SHELLMETAS`) is required to force Procmail to run the subprocess in a shell (otherwise it would pass through the literal string `content=$(cat)` as the value of the option `-d`).

In some more detail, the recipe

```
:0
| variable=$(cat)
```

would run a shell as a subprocess, and assign the message's contents as the value of the shell variable `variable`, but then immediately exit, which of course loses any effects of variable assignments which happened within that subprocess.